# Dividing an object into N amount of equal parts

Tags: c#, arrays, math

I have an object (it's actually a 2D array but for simplicity I've found it useful to imagine it's a rectangle). The rectangle is 40 units wide on its X axis. I need to be able to divide this rectangle on the X plane by N number of dividers and return the unit number that this divider falls on (i.e. the array index). So, if there were two dividers the results would be 10 and 30.

I have another array to hold the results which I initialize with the number of dividers. I'd like to populate this results array in a loop, something like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDividers; i++)
   {
      resultsArray[i] = some calculation involving i, the rectangle size and the number of dividers rounded up to the nearest integer
   }
```

I'll probably kick myself when I read the answer but I'm having a bit of a brain freeze at the moment! Many thanks.

Comment: How do you derive 10 and 30 from 2 dividers along 40 units?..

Comment: `int i = 1;` ... ouch! Arrays have 0-based indices ...

Comment: Please give more detailed example, with real numbers.

Comment: According to Sayse I would expect 0 and 20 as result instead of 10 and 30. So please explain how the "deviders" should devide your object.

Comment: The problem here is that your example locations of the dividers do NOT divide the rectangle into equal areas. You have not stated the rationale for how you have divided it. To divide a line of length 40 into equal parts using two dividers, you would choose locations of 13 and 27 (to the nearest integer).

Comment: @ all, one moment please, I'll post a picture that will help

Comment: If you've got 2 EQUAL dividers shouldn't it be 13.3333r  and 26.6666r?

Comment: Adding to my above comment: Starting with index 1 would only make sense if you set index 0 outside the loop. But if you created the array with `new int[numberOfDividers]` you'll run into IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: Guys, thanks, you've just made me see my dumb error, of course the numbers would be 13.3 and 26.6 so it's simply dividers / 40. Told you I was having a brain freeze! Many thanks.

Comment: SO etiquette - should I delete this question? It's not useful for others

Comment: No, it's 40 / (dividers **+1** ) . If you want 2 dividers, you want 3 parts which start at 0, 14, 27 (according to your round to ceiling requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
//This will return the integer dividers as evenly spaced out as possible.
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDividers(this int totalLength, int dividersCount)
{
    //Error cases
    if (dividersCount > totalLength)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    //Get trivial cases out of the way.
    if (dividersCount <= 0)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var partitionLength = totalLength / (dividersCount + 1); //n dividers means n+1 partitions.
    var partitionTotalError = totalLength % (dividersCount + 1); //Integer division will truncate so we need to evaluate the error so we can distribute it later on as evenly as possible.
    var counter = partitionLength;

    while (counter < totalLength)
    {
        yield return counter;
        var currentStep = partitionLength + (partitionTotalError-- > 0 ? 1 : 0); //distribute error in middle and last step.
        counter += currentStep;
    }            
}
```